# Media query is not applying properly to grid

Tags: html, css, node.js, grid, media-queries

I tried to set .col as width equals 100% so my content can be stack over each other when it get to the screen width of 768px in the media queries. But it's not working. And I already have the grid file linked in the HTML head. Here is my HTML file and CSS below:

```html
<header>
    <div class="text-box">
        <h1>Kindly Click on any wallet related to you</h1>
    </div>
</header>
<section class="section-pages">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col span-1-of-4">
            <p>Welcome to the future</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col span-1-of-4">
            <p>Welcome to the future</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col span-1-of-4">
            <p>Welcome to the future</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col span-1-of-4">
            <p>Welcome to the future</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

```css
.row{
    max-width: 1095px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

header{
    background-image: url("tezoz.png");
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
}

@media(max-width: 768px) {
    .col{
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Or could it be that I can only use the grid file once cos I am confused

Comment: Can you put the grid file also? It will help others to understand the problem here.

Comment: you can use col-xs, col-sm, col-md, col-lg for column's separate screen size behavior.

Comment: I am not sure i know how to use that. Is it bootstrap